# Hierarchy of fusion categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, fusion-categories

There is a large hierarchy of foobar fusion categories, where foobar is a special property. How does this correlate with the properties of their Clebsch-Gordan (or analogue, I think those are the F-) symbols?

- set of fusion rules $A\bigotimes B=\bigoplus C$, with an identity $1$: not a category unless associative?
- just associative: (I looked up the Wiki, declare everything self-dual and all properties of a fusion category are fulfilled, assuming $A\bigotimes A=1\bigoplus \neq 1$, $A\bigotimes \neq A=\bigoplus \neq 1$?!)
- ? : (pentagon=Biedenharn-Elliott rule holds - is pentagon stronger than associative?)
- pointed: ?
- spherical: some symmetry of the CG symbol?
- modular symbol: ?
- modular data: (even stronger than modular symbol = same as braided?)
- braided: (hexagon=Racah rule holds?)